# htaccess rewrite rule for all images in a folder to another domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a live site (livesite.com) and a dev site (devsite.com). The images directory is so huge that I am not able to copy it from livesite.com to devsite.com. Therefore, I want to add a rewrite rule for devsite.com to fetch the image from livesite.com (the directory structure on both sites are identical - its just the domain that's different)

It's a wordpress site so the images are located in this structure for each month;

```
/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/image.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/image.jpg
etc..
```

I need to add a rewrite rule just for everything in the 2015 directory.

So far, this is what I have in the htaccess file in the root of devsite.com; It's targetting a specific sub-directory in the 2015 folder and I can't even get this to work - the images are still trying to be retrieved from the devsite.com domain rather than livesite.com

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /wp-content/uploads/2015/01/(.*)$ http://livesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
```

I suspect I have made a bumbling error here - any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the pattern, which starts with a slash, see [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> **Per-directory Rewrites**
>   - The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context.

So, in your case it should be

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2015/01/(.*)$ http://livesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
```

Although, since you want to cover the whole `2015` subdirectory, you can simplify this to

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2015/(.*)$ http://livesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/$1 [R,NC,L]
```

or even

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2015/(.*)$ http://livesite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Whilst this looks correct, the same thing happens - my website tries to grab images from devsite.com rather than livesite.com so perhaps something else is awry in my htaccess or suchlike. I will try it with just these rules and nothing else